# Images won't show on Website

Tags: html, css, image

I cannot seem to get my images to show up when they are on my webpage. They are fine when they are on my own local file, but as soon as I upload the page to FTP I get an error 404 image not found. I have tried changing the path but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is a link to the site and the code is below:

http://79.170.44.107/tadesign.com/

```
<div id="container">

<div id="topbody">

<div id="topbar">

<div>

<div id="logo">

<h2 id="name">MEA</h2>

<img src="images/MEALOGO.png" />

</div>
```

Contact

Candidates

Comment: Is it a WordPress website?

Comment: does the chmod is ok ?

Comment: You cannot see the images because they are not there, check the logo for example: http://79.170.44.107/tadesign.com/images/MEALOGO.png Is your images folder in the root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason they aren't loading is because they are not in a 'images' directory on your server.

for example:

```
http://79.170.44.107/tadesign.com/images/MEALOGO.png
```

gives a 404 error, but

```
http://79.170.44.107/tadesign.com/MEALOGO.png
```

works fine.

Either put your images in a directory called 'images' or remove 'images' from your src's

Comment: That was it. I hadn't put the images directory on the server. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your image isn't located in 'images/MEALOGO.png' its located at 'MEALOGO.png'.

Use this instead:

```
<img src="MEALOGO.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Looked at your website code and found out that it works when you take out the images folder. It  either means the `images` folder doesn't exist or you're referring to another copy of the image that's outside the `images folder`.

So instead of

```
<img src="images/MEALOGO.png" />
```

Do this

```
<img src="MEALOGO.png" />
```

Or move `MEALOGO.png` into the images folder if it exists.